# Como mapear campos de classes com nomes diferentes das colunas da base de dados?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot, h2database

Estou usando a IDE IntelliJ. Tenho a seguinte *model*:

```
@Entity(name = "carro")
@Data
public class Carro {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String tipo;
    private String descricao;
    private String urlFoto;
    private String urlVideo;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
}
```

Percebi que a JPA não reconhece na forma padrão, por exemplo:

```
public class Carro {
```

Ao adicionar a anotaçao `@Entity` eu gostaria que ele entendesse que a classe `Carro` seria a tabela `carro` no banco de dados

Para funcionar corretamente eu tive que adicionar dessa maneira no `@Entity`

```
@Entity(name = "carro")
```

Assim mesmo com as colunas `urlFoto` por exemplo, ao realizar a consulta o hibernate deu erro dizendo que o campo `urlFoto` não existe, ou seja, ele não converteu para `url_foto` do banco. Mas ao usar o H2, ele executou normalmente, ou seja, reconheceu e fez a conversão para o formato do banco de dados

Quando for mysql

Sempre terei que user a anotação `@Column?`? ou

Tenho que fazer alguma configuração adicional?

**[EDIT]**
No meu arquivo `application.properties` está assim:

```
# MySQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/carros?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

#SQL.
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

# logging
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O comportamento que você espera pode ser implementado por meio de uma `ImplicitNamingStrategy` ou `PhysicalNamingStrategy`. Esse é o [mecanismo que determina como o nomes de classes e campos será traduzido para tabelas e colunas](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/naming.html).

Acredito que uma `PhysicalNamingStrategy` que já faz o que você precisa é a que vem como *default* no Spring ([link do github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/7df18d9a91f1cee8f0f5a4e0a17d56c85ca75835/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/hibernate/SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.java)):

```
import java.util.Locale;

import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;

/**
 * Hibernate {@link PhysicalNamingStrategy} that follows Spring recommended naming
 * conventions.
 *
 * @author Phillip Webb
 * @author Madhura Bhave
 * @since 1.4.0
 */
public class SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy implements PhysicalNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalCatalogName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        return apply(name, jdbcEnvironment);
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalSchemaName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        return apply(name, jdbcEnvironment);
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        return apply(name, jdbcEnvironment);
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalSequenceName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        return apply(name, jdbcEnvironment);
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        return apply(name, jdbcEnvironment);
    }

    private Identifier apply(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        if (name == null) {
            return null;
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(name.getText().replace('.', '_'));
        for (int i = 1; i < builder.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (isUnderscoreRequired(builder.charAt(i - 1), builder.charAt(i), builder.charAt(i + 1))) {
                builder.insert(i++, '_');
            }
        }
        return getIdentifier(builder.toString(), name.isQuoted(), jdbcEnvironment);
    }

    /**
     * Get an identifier for the specified details. By default this method will return an
     * identifier with the name adapted based on the result of
     * {@link #isCaseInsensitive(JdbcEnvironment)}
     * @param name the name of the identifier
     * @param quoted if the identifier is quoted
     * @param jdbcEnvironment the JDBC environment
     * @return an identifier instance
     */
    protected Identifier getIdentifier(String name, boolean quoted, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        if (isCaseInsensitive(jdbcEnvironment)) {
            name = name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
        }
        return new Identifier(name, quoted);
    }

    /**
     * Specify whether the database is case sensitive.
     * @param jdbcEnvironment the JDBC environment which can be used to determine case
     * @return true if the database is case insensitive sensitivity
     */
    protected boolean isCaseInsensitive(JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isUnderscoreRequired(char before, char current, char after) {
        return Character.isLowerCase(before) && Character.isUpperCase(current) && Character.isLowerCase(after);
    }

}
```

Em um projeto Spring Boot basta usar a configuração:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

Comment: Como eu importo do Spring?

Comment: Quando coloquei isso aqui no arquivo `application.properties`: `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy` tive o seguinte erro: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Could not instantiate named strategy class [org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy]

Comment: Antes estava assim: #spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Comment: @adventistaam Se vc já está em um projeto Spring Boot, e dependendo da versao, basta usar `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy`

Comment: Isso mesmo... Deu certo... Se puder adicionar na resposta, eu agradeço

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilisar a anotação `@Column(name = "url_foto")` acima do campo `urlFoto`.

Usamos esta anotação quando o nome da coluna na base de dados é diferente do nome do campo da classe.

Comment: Pois é... quando uso o banco de dados H2, ele sozinho faz essa conversão pra mim